# Java8: why two composition methods: andThen and compose?

Tags: functional-programming, composition, java8

As a beginner in both java8 and functional programming, I think I'm missing something when reading about function composition since I cannot find a reason why there are two methods that do this, `andThen` and `compose`.

Since `f.andThen(g)` is exactly the same as `g.compose(f)`, why are both needed, in which cases would using one of them be better than the other?

Comment: They aren't. It's just that minimality isn't the most important quality for an API.

Comment: But... there are four methods in the Function interface, minimal enough... Two of which are the named ones... So how about redundancy?

Comment: People who are used to mathematical functions and data flow programming find `a.compose(b)` easier to understand. People who are new to functionality find `b.andThen(a)` *much* easier. The Java authors think that it's more important to accomodate different users than to avoid redundancy.

Comment: @KilianFoth: although for the mathematically inclined, `a ∘ b` would be even better, but until the Java designers realize that operators are just names like any other, and we should be allowed to choose them as freely as any other names, that's not gonna happen.

Comment: I think you can conveniently use it to change associativity style of functions from `(a (b c))` to `((a b) c)`, which I suppose is just a matter of convenience or personal taste.

Comment: Also, a colleague of mine recently argued that g.compose(f).apply(x) is closer to the mathematical, g(f(x)), whilst g.andThen(f).apply(x) is closer to... plain English :).

Comment: F# and some other FP languages also provide compose and flip compose operators so I don't think this is just a Java thing

Comment: @JorgWMittag ... The problem with allowing arbitrary operators is how do you assign precedence to them? As far as I see, there are only two practical approaches: either use fixed precedence (eg left-to-right, as Smalltalk uses, which results in surprising behavior for expressions like `a+b*2`, which calculates twice the total of a and b) or only let operators work on a single pair of types, so the first definition of an operator sets precedence and prevents any further definition (as used in Haskell, for example). Unfortunately, this doesn't really work well for OO languages.

Comment: @Jules: Fortress did it by defining precedence relative to other operators. If two operators don't have a defined relative precedence, using them together in the same expression without disambiguating them with parentheses is a syntax error. I believe Perl6 is similar. Scala defines a set of operator characters, precedence is assigned based on the first character of the method name, e.g. all methods starting with `+` have the same precedence, all methods starting with `*` have the same (higher) precedence, and so on. I like the Fortress version the best.

Comment: @Jules As in Scala, "operators" would just be methods with non-alphanumeric names. `a ∘ b` would mean `a.∘(b)`. The precedence follows. The irrational fear of non-alphanumeric characters in names baffles me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`compose` is a traditional operation.  Its order was decided by mathematicians. However, like a lot of things originally decided by mathematicians, the order isn't a very convenient convention for programmers.  We include the operation anyway because functional programming has strong ties to mathematics.

In languages like Haskell, you only have the compose operator, so you have to read and write everything backwards, like:

```
filter even . concat . filter ((> 2) . length)
```

The filter for length greater than 2 happens first, then the `concat`, then the filter for even numbers.  You get used to this, but it's still annoying, so other languages create compose operators like `andThen` that let you write a composed function in the order it executes.  Anyone could easily add such an operator to their program in Haskell too, for that matter, it just wouldn't be idiomatic Haskell any more.

Feel free to use whichever one makes it easier for you to translate from your domain.

Comment: It's worth noting that one of the core Haskell modules, `Control.Arrow` does define an operator that does exactly this, `>>>`. It composes any types that are "arrows", but the definition of arrows includes standard functions. I think quite a few people use it just for this reason, and I wouldn't really describe it as " non-idiomatic ".

Answer (score 1):

=v= There is also a `BiFunction` interface that does for two arguments what `Function` does for one.  This interface has no `compose` because that won't work on two arguments, but it does have `andThen`.  So one advantage of `Function#andThen` is consistency with `BiFunction`.